# How to close an Apache thread from PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, apache

I am trying to get PHP to tell Apache to close the connection and respectively free the worker thread. The reason being is I have a script that is invoked with client request and takes up some time to process but returns nothing to the client, so it just makes no sense to keep the thread occupied. The code I'm currently using:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Content-Length: 0');
flush();
ob_end_flush();
header('Connection: Close');
```

Since I'm sending an additional asynchronous request to this script from the original user request, `Content-Length: 0` won't mess up the response of the client request.

Anyway when I go to monitor what the server is doing I see that there is a worker thread occupied with the long-running request which is exactly what I want to not happen. I want the script to run silently in the back without occupying Apache threads. How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't actually multi-threading. You can multi-thread using `pthreads` (not trivial as it usually requires re-compiling PHP) and I hear that can be done even within an Apache process. Or use a queue system such as Gearman or Resque.

Comment: If you are on shared hosting however, it might be worth trying [`pfork`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) - there aren't many options here other than `cron`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bad practice and a whole lot of trouble, e.g. with concurrency and load balancing.

Consider implementing task queue:

1. Your client wants to add a task to the queue at will.
2. Client sends request to Apache, which runs PHP code.
3. PHP parses input and constructs a task, which is added to the queue.
4. Server returns empty response to client.

Then, set up a daemon or cron job that processes the aforementioned queue in the background, outside of Apache.

This gives you fine control over what happens when, without need for hacks like that. As a bonus, you keep your resource usage in check, by having control over how fast the queue is processed. (Especially useful if you talk to external API that limits traffic.)

If you want your queue to be parallel, nothing prevents you from that - consider setting up a number of task pools, and each task upon creating is assigned to random task pool. Then, set up daemon instance for each task pool - no need for PHP threads or anything like that.

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't see how I can achieve what I'm trying with a queue and cron. What the "long request" actually is a private socket server. I need the server to be started as soon as the request is sent and running a cronjob every second is definitely not a smart idea :?

Comment: That's where daemon approach would be better - let persistent PHP daemon know you want to open a socket, and it opens it up. The difficult part is to figure out how to do interop right - monitoring text files isn't very pretty.

Comment: If multiple sockets need to be opened at the same time, instead of trying to make persistent daemon multi-threaded, you could just spawn detached PHP processes using command like `exec()`.

Comment: I think your last suggestion would be the best approach, mainly because I don't know what daemon is, however, is there any way I can run a file with `exec` without knowing the path to `php.exe` ( for example on a shared hosting machine )

Comment: Daemon is something that runs as a background system service. To locate php executable, you can try using commands such as `command -v php` and `which php`, providing they're available. I'm surprised you can open sockets on shared hosting machine.